# How can I best translate this Java method to C#?

Tags: c#, java

I want to translate my Java code to C# but I'm having difficultly in finding equivalents for `String.equalsIgnoreCase` and `StringBuffer`.

This my Java syntax:

```
public static boolean isPalindrom (String _text)
{
     return _text.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(_text).reverse().toString());
}
```

And this my C# code

```
public static bool isPalindrom(string _text)
{
    char[] charArray = _text.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return _text.Compare(new StringBuilder(_text).Remove());
}
```

Comment: And why do you want to do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
public static bool isPalindrome(string _text)
{
    return _text.SequenceEqual(_text.Reverse());
}
```

Both [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are extension methods from Linq. Of course, you don't have to check every character to test if a string palindromic. What about this:

```
public static bool isPalindrome(string _text)
{
    var halfLen = (int)Math.Ceiling(_text.Length / 2.0);
    return _text.Take(halfLen).SequenceEqual(_text.Reverse().Take(halfLen));
}
```

To make this method case-insensitive, you can simply do this:

```
public static bool isPalindrome(string _text)
{
    _text = _text.ToUpperInvariant();
    var halfLen = _text.Length / 2;
    return _text.Take(halfLen).SequenceEqual(_text.Reverse().Take(halfLen));
}
```

Comment: i want to translate this java code return _text.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(_text).reverse().toString()); to c#....i have dificultly..whit StringBuffer is not applicable in C#

Comment: ok i'think you sholved my problem